WSO2 Inbound endpoint with dynamic parameter
By providing the static values into WSO2 inbound endpoint it works fine as in the below given example.
Looking for a solution that will dynamically pick the value from configuration (i.e. from deployment.toml or axis2.xml etc) so that listener should connect during system startup.
  <inboundEndpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="RabbitMQConsumer"     sequence="amqpSeq" onError="amqpErrorSeq" protocol="rabbitmq" suspend="false">
      <parameters>
      <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
      <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
      <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">AMQPConnectionFactory</parameter>
      <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.host.name">localhost</parameter>
      <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.port">5672</parameter>
      <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.user.name">guest</parameter>
      <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.password">guest</parameter>
      <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.name">queue</parameter>
      <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.name">exchange</parameter>
      <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.enabled">false</parameter>
      </parameters>
  </inboundEndpoint>

below are some examples tried with inbound endpoint parameters but no success yet.
1>
<parameter name="rabbitmq.server.host.name">${rabbitmq:host}</parameter> 

2>
<parameter name="rabbitmq.server.host.name">$axis2:rabbitmq.server.host.name</parameter>

3> tried from registry
<parameter name="rabbitmq.server.host.name">
            <![CDATA[json-eval(get-property('gov:/rmqconnection/RMQ.json', 'rmq_host'))]]>
</parameter>


You can use $SYSTEM:SOME_PROPERTY_NAME to dynamically set an environment variable or $FILE:SOME_PROPERTY_NAME to set the value using a file.properties file located at <MI_HOME>/conf directory as follows,
<parameter name="rabbitmq.server.host.name">$SYSTEM:RABBIT_HOST_PROPERTY</parameter>

Refer the following official documentation for more information https://mi.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/injecting-parameters/#inbound-endpoint-parameters
